# How to change text color according to valid(@mentions) and all hashtags?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I wanted to display hashtags and valid mentions with different colors in the text.

I got helped with this code which works only for hashtags

```
RichText _convertHashtag(String text) {
  List<String> split = text.split(RegExp("#"));
  List<String> hashtags = split.getRange(1, split.length).fold([], (t, e) {
    var texts = e.split(" ");
    if (texts.length > 1) {
      return List.from(t)
        ..addAll(["#${texts.first}", "${e.substring(texts.first.length)}"]);
    }
    return List.from(t)..add("#${texts.first}");
  });
  return RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      children: [TextSpan(text: split.first)]..addAll(hashtags
          .map((text) => text.contains("#")
              ? TextSpan(text: text, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
              : TextSpan(text: text))
          .toList()),
    ),
  );
}
```

I modified it like:

```
  List valid_mentions = ['@mention1', '@mention2'];//these are the valid mention

  RichText _convertHashtag(String text) {
    List<String> split = text.split(RegExp("#|@"));
    List<String> hashtags = split.getRange(1, split.length).fold([], (t, e) {
      var texts = e.split(" ");

      //here adding `@` sign and `#` sign to the given texts and storing them in the `hashtags` list
      if (texts.length > 1) {
        if (valid_mentions.contains(texts.first))
          return List.from(t)
            ..addAll(["@${texts.first}", "${e.substring(texts.first.length)}"]);
        else if (text.contains('@${texts.first}')) {
          return List.from(t)
            ..addAll(["@${texts.first}", "${e.substring(texts.first.length)}"]);
        } else
          return List.from(t)
            ..addAll(["#${texts.first}", "${e.substring(texts.first.length)}"]);
      } else {
        if (valid_mentions.contains(texts.first))
          return List.from(t)..addAll(["@${texts.first}"]);
        else if (text.contains('@${texts.first}')) {
          return List.from(t)..addAll(["@${texts.first}"]);
        } else
          return List.from(t)..addAll(["#${texts.first}"]);
      }
    });
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: [TextSpan(text: split.first)]..addAll(hashtags.map((text) {
            return text.contains("@")
                ? valid_mentions.contains(text)
                    ? //checking if the mention is valid
                    TextSpan(
                        text: text,
                        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                          ..onTap = () {
                            print(text);
                          },
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
                    : TextSpan(
                        text: text,
                      )
                : text.contains("#")
                    ? TextSpan(
                        text: text,
                        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                          ..onTap = () {
                            print(text);
                          },
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
                    : TextSpan(
                        text: text,
                      );
          }).toList()),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I am able to make the required changes, but i belive its not an optimized way and there is a lot of boiler plate code. How can i optimize it?

input:"I love #flutter #android @mention1 @mention2 @mention3 "

output:"I love **#flutter** **#android** **@mention1** **@mention2** @mention3 "

here @mention3 is not hyperlinked because its not an valid mention.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've understood, you want to highlight hashtags and mentions (pre stored in a list) in a String.

Let me break this into 2 parts, the first would be to extract the hashtags & mentions from the text.

```dart
List<String> getAllHashtags(String text) {
  final regexp = RegExp(r'\#[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b()');

  List<String> hashtags = [];

  regexp.allMatches(text).forEach((element) {
    if (element.group(0) != null) {
      hashtags.add(element.group(0).toString());
    }
  });

  return hashtags;
}

List<String> getAllMentions(String text) {
  final regexp = RegExp(r'\@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b()');

  List<String> mentions = [];

  regexp.allMatches(text).forEach((element) {
    if (element.group(0) != null) {
      mentions.add(element.group(0).toString());
    }
  });

  return mentions;
}
```

The above code snippet will successfully extract hashtags & mentions from the given sentence and return it as a list.

The next step would be to build the RichText with the different TextSpans.

```dart
RichText buildHighlightedText(String text) {
  // clean the text
  text = cleanText(text);

  List<String> validMentions = ["@mention1", "@mention2"];
  
  List<String> hashtags = getAllHashtags(text);
  List<String> mentions = getAllMentions(text);

  List<TextSpan> textSpans = [];

  text.split(" ").forEach((value) {
    if (hashtags.contains(value)) {
      textSpans.add(TextSpan(
        text: '$value ',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ));
    } else if (mentions.contains(value) && validMentions.contains(value)) {
      textSpans.add(TextSpan(
        text: '$value ',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ));
    } else {
      textSpans.add(TextSpan(text: '$value '));
    }
  });

  return RichText(text: TextSpan(children: textSpans));
}
```

The text has been split by empty spaces, and filters hashtags/mentions and returns differently styled TextSpans for each. This is a more concise and cleaner way of doing what you're looking for.

**Here's an example:**

[image: running the application with an example]

**Edit:**

In order to parse hashtags without spaces, we need to add each instance with a space in front.

```dart
String cleanText(String text) {
  text = text.replaceAllMapped(
      RegExp(r'\w#+'), (Match m) => "${m[0]?.split('').join(" ")}");

  text = text.replaceAllMapped(
      RegExp(r'\w@+'), (Match m) => "${m[0]?.split('').join(" ")}");

  return text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  , that worked pretty well. One more thing, what changes need to be made if we want #hello#world or @mention1@mention2 even to be the valid hashtags and mention. As we are using text.split(" ").forEach((value) , they wouldn't split and will not be considered.

Comment: That's true. In that case the text has to be edited to have spaces in front of the values. I've edited my answer. @kanwarmanraj