# How to change the color of specific expressions in text in flutter

Tags: flutter, richtext, textspan

I'm trying to build an instagram clone and I want if the user tags someone in the comments, the tag text should appear blue (as in real Instagram). [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nLdC.png). I've used regex to recognise the tags from the text but can't figure out how to color them as the user can place a tag anywhere in the comment. I tried using `RichText` widget along with `TextSpan` but quickly realised it was way too hardcoded. Is there any direct and easy way for this situation?

PS: Sorry for the bad title...

Comment: Maybe this could help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68290810/how-to-change-text-color-according-to-validmentions-and-all-hashtags)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this first create a list of strings:

```
List<String> _tags = [];
```

Then create a function that will recognize when someone is tagged:

```
  List<String> _extractTags(String text) {
    List<String> tags = [];
    RegExp exp = RegExp(r'\B@\w+');
    Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(text);
    for (RegExpMatch match in matches) {
      tags.add(match.group(0));
    }
    return tags;
  }
```

Then use this function inside TextField's onChange method:

```
onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _tags = _extractTags(value);
                });
              },
```

This will put tags inside `_tags` list. When you use this list, use it like below:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _tags.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    String tag = _tags[index];
    TextStyle defaultStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 16);
    TextStyle tagStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16);
    List<TextSpan> spans = [];
    if (tag == null) {
      spans.add(TextSpan(text: '', style: defaultStyle));
    } else {
      String text = tag.substring(1);
      spans.add(TextSpan(text: '@', style: defaultStyle));
      spans.add(TextSpan(text: text, style: tagStyle));
    }
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(children: spans),
    );
  },
),
```